# Swiper.js breakpoints autoplay issue

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

i'm setting up swiper.js library (http://idangero.us/swiper/) and i have a problem with settings. I'm try to setup swiper to start autoplay on desktop size and stop autoplay on mobile (eg. 768px down). Everything work fine on desktop and even if you try responsive without refresh page. Problem begin on mobile size after page refresh. Swiper ignore all settings until page resize.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWdera

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      autoplay: {
          delay: 1000
        },
      breakpoints: {
        768: {
          autoplay: {
            delay: false
          }
        }
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works after reboot. You need to change the autoplay object to boolean

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  autoplay: {
      delay: 1000
    },
  breakpoints: {
    768: {
      autoplay: false
    }
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

Comment: Doing this won't work properly on a newer version of the swiper. 
use `autoplay: { enabled: false }` instead

Answer (score 1):

In swiper v9.2.2, and with help from @MNN TNK's comment, I had to use the following to disable autoplay on mobile...

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  autoplay: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  breakpoints: {
    768: {
      autoplay: {
        enabled: true,
        delay: 1000,
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```